# Use same value in Insert (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I write a script to populate the database with values

Here is script row

```
INSERT INTO AbpUsers(EmailAddress, IsActive, IsDeleted, IsEmailConfirmed, Name, NormalizedEmailAddress, NormalizedUserName, Surname, UserName, AccessFailedCount, CreationTime, IsLockoutEnabled, IsPhoneNumberConfirmed, IsTwoFactorEnabled, Password, ShouldChangePasswordOnNextLogin)
VALUES 
('faithsdispatching@yahoo.com', 1, 0, 1, '', UPPER (EmailAddress), '', '', '', 0, GETDATE(), 1, 1, 0, 'AQAAAAEAACcQAAAAEHriGqDq6AuQs33CBdyNdwuiZboPua2e6aXn9MjB/qzo44kbXAAsIY77BIfzKLJD1Q==', 0)
```

For `NormalizedEmailAddress` field I need to  use `EmailAddress` to Upper

I try to use this `UPPER (EmailAddress)` but get this error

> Line 1: Invalid column name 'EmailAddress'.

Any ideas on how I can use `EmailAddress` column?

Comment: You can't "reuse" the email address value `faithsdispatching@yahoo.com` in the `VALUES` clause.  You will have to repeat it.

Comment: It might be better to only have one copy of email address. Either store it as upper case initially or use the `UPPER` function as when you need to.

Comment: Why not used computed columns? Otherwise you could end up updating one coln and not the other, and then your data integrity is affected.

Comment: Seems you haven't come across my case-sensitive email server. What about just using a case-insensitive collation for that column?

Comment: Sorry just seems like you are using the wrong tool for the job. Either have a computed column, or use a CI collation

Comment: I using right tool @Charlieface

Comment: So what happens if someone updates `EmailAddress`, how do you keep `NormalizedEmailAddress` in sync? This is why you should either store it case-insensitive anyway, or use a computed column

Answer (score 2):

I don't think what you're asking is possible at the moment.

As a quick workaround, you can insert your data into a temporary table, run the `UPPER()` command on the column to hit them all at once, and then `SELECT INTO` your desired table from your temporary table.

```
CREATE TABLE #TemporaryAbpUsers
(
    EmailAddress...,
    IsActive...
);

INSERT INTO #AbpUsers(EmailAddress, IsActive, IsDeleted, IsEmailConfirmed, Name, NormalizedEmailAddress, NormalizedUserName, Surname, UserName, AccessFailedCount, CreationTime, IsLockoutEnabled, IsPhoneNumberConfirmed, IsTwoFactorEnabled, Password, ShouldChangePasswordOnNextLogin)
VALUES 
('faithsdispatching@yahoo.com', 1, 0, 1, '', 'faithsdispatching@yahoo.com', '', '', '', 0, GETDATE(), 1, 1, 0, 'AQAAAAEAACcQAAAAEHriGqDq6AuQs33CBdyNdwuiZboPua2e6aXn9MjB/qzo44kbXAAsIY77BIfzKLJD1Q==', 0);

UPDATE #TemporaryAbpUsers
SET NormalizedEmailAddress = UPPER(NormalizedEmailAddress);

SELECT * INTO AbpUsers
FROM #TemporaryAbpUsers;
```

Comment: or first migration is add empty string and second migration is to update all rows

Answer (score 1):

Just change `UPPER(EmailAddress)` to `UPPER ('faithsdispatching@yahoo.com')`

---

```
INSERT INTO AbpUsers(EmailAddress, IsActive, IsDeleted, IsEmailConfirmed, Name, NormalizedEmailAddress, NormalizedUserName, Surname, UserName, AccessFailedCount, CreationTime, IsLockoutEnabled, IsPhoneNumberConfirmed, IsTwoFactorEnabled, Password, ShouldChangePasswordOnNextLogin)
VALUES 
('faithsdispatching@yahoo.com', 1, 0, 1, '', UPPER ('faithsdispatching@yahoo.com'), '', '', '', 0, GETDATE(), 1, 1, 0, 'AQAAAAEAACcQAAAAEHriGqDq6AuQs33CBdyNdwuiZboPua2e6aXn9MjB/qzo44kbXAAsIY77BIfzKLJD1Q==', 0)
```

Comment: It's not an option

Answer (score 1):

Use a variable for EmailAddress

```
DECLARE @EmailAddress NVARCHAR(100);

SET @EmailAddress = N'faithsdispatching@yahoo.com';
INSERT INTO AbpUsers(EmailAddress, IsActive, IsDeleted, IsEmailConfirmed, Name, NormalizedEmailAddress, NormalizedUserName, Surname, UserName, AccessFailedCount, CreationTime, IsLockoutEnabled, IsPhoneNumberConfirmed, IsTwoFactorEnabled, Password, ShouldChangePasswordOnNextLogin)
VALUES 
(@EmailAddress, 1, 0, 1, '', UPPER(@EmailAddress), '', '', '', 0, GETDATE(), 1, 1, 0, 'AQAAAAEAACcQAAAAEHriGqDq6AuQs33CBdyNdwuiZboPua2e6aXn9MjB/qzo44kbXAAsIY77BIfzKLJD1Q==', 0);
```

For multiple inserts, then you could try an Insert-From-Select-From-Values.

```
INSERT INTO AbpUsers(EmailAddress, IsActive, IsDeleted, IsEmailConfirmed, Name, NormalizedEmailAddress, NormalizedUserName, Surname, UserName, AccessFailedCount, CreationTime, IsLockoutEnabled, IsPhoneNumberConfirmed, IsTwoFactorEnabled, Password, ShouldChangePasswordOnNextLogin)
SELECT EmailAddress, IsActive, IsDeleted, IsEmailConfirmed, Name, 
UPPER(EmailAddress) AS NormalizedEmailAddress, 
NormalizedUserName, Surname, UserName, AccessFailedCount, CreationTime, IsLockoutEnabled, IsPhoneNumberConfirmed, IsTwoFactorEnabled, Password, ShouldChangePasswordOnNextLogin
FROM (VALUES
  ('faithsdispatching@yahoo.com', 1, 0, 1, '', '', '', '', 0, GETDATE(), 1, 1, 0, 'AQAAAAEAACcQAAAAEHriGqDq6AuQs33CBdyNdwuiZboPua2e6aXn9MjB/qzo44kbXAAsIY77BIfzKLJD1Q==', 0)
, ('hellbendingsextra@funky.net', 1, 0, 1, '', '', '', '', 0, GETDATE(), 1, 1, 0, 'AQBBBBEAACcQAAAAEHriGqDq6AuQs33CBdyNdwuiZboPua2e6aXn9MjB/qzo44kbXAAsIY77BIfzKLJD2Q==', 0) 
, ('yellowriverfishing@asia.org', 1, 0, 1, '', '', '', '', 0, GETDATE(), 1, 1, 0, 'AQCCCCEAACcQAAAAEHriGqDq6AuQs33CBdyNdwuiZboPua2e6aXn9MjB/qzo44kbXAAsIY77BIfzKLJD3Q==', 0) 
) q(EmailAddress, IsActive, IsDeleted, IsEmailConfirmed, Name, 
NormalizedUserName, Surname, UserName, AccessFailedCount, CreationTime, IsLockoutEnabled, IsPhoneNumberConfirmed, IsTwoFactorEnabled, Password, ShouldChangePasswordOnNextLogin)
```

Comment: I was thinking about this too, but if there's a list of 100+ emails, I think declaring and setting a variable might be more work than it's worth and doesn't save any keystrokes.

Comment: Well, the declare is only required once in the same transaction. But okay, for 100+. Hmm...

Comment: Added an extra solution.